# Getting JIRA system information from command line

Tags: jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get JIRA system information from command line. I would like to monitor the Java VM memory statistics from a dashboard.

I am aware of JIRA CLI, but, dont see any options that would help me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use jira-python and the server_info method, e.g.

```
def connect_jira(log, options):
'''
Connect to JIRA. Prompt for a password if none was specified.
Return None on error
'''
try:
    log.info("Connecting to JIRA: %s" % options.jira_server)
    jira_options = {'server': options.jira_server}
    if options.jira_password:
        jira_password = options.jira_password
    else:
        jira_password = getpass.getpass()

    jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,
                # Note the tuple
                basic_auth=(options.jira_user, 
                            jira_password))
    # Test the connection by retrieving server information
    info = jira.server_info()

    return jira
except Exception,e:
    log.error("Failed to connect to JIRA: %s" % e)
    return None
```